# Looping over the threshold area does not change pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, steganography

I am currently working on a design of steganography system that detects a certain area in an image using several techniques (K-means, Canny edge detection) using Python and OpenCV library.
I am facing a huge problem updating the image pixel values to contain my secret data in the least significant bit.

I started with finding the threshold after several calculations.

`thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(imgray,100,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)`

And to test the area I did the following:

```
Testim=np.copy(originalImage) 
Testim[thresh==0]=[0,255,0]
plt.imshow(Testim)
plt.show()
```

and it showed this image which indicates the area I want to loop over:

[Image showing after the threshold Isolation in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bbBS.png)

After that I went through a loop that I will show you a snippet of it, it iterates over the RGB values and changes each least significant bit with a bit from the secret data. I would like to note that the original image shape is (1024,1024,3) and the shape of the image[thresh==0] is (863843, 3) :

```
 for i in range(image[thresh==0].shape[0]): 
      # convert RGB values to binary format
      r, g, b = to_bin(image[thresh==0][i])
              # modify the least significant bit only if there is still data to store
      if data_index < data_len:
              # least significant red pixel bit
        image[thresh==0][i][0] =int (r[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        data_index += 1 
      if data_index < data_len:
              # least significant green pixel bit
        image[thresh==0][i][1] = int (g[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        data_index += 1
      if data_index < data_len:
              # least significant blue pixel bit
        image[thresh==0][i][2] = int (b[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        data_index += 1
                # if data is encoded, just break out of the loop
      if data_index >= data_len:
        plt.imshow(image)
        break
    return image,thresh
```

The problem is that the values of RGB are not changing in and out of the loop at all, I added some print statements, and it keeps showing zero, I also tried to assign 1 explicitly, and it didn't work either.

**I want to note that this is part of the encode function only**

I would appreciate your help with this

Comment: If you're saving the result as a JPEG, the bottom few bits won't be consistent because of lossy compression.

Comment: I tried it over png and it didn't work either

Comment: Are you really computing `image[thresh==0]` millions of times? Why not put that in a separate variable?

Comment: “I added some print statements, and it keeps showing zero” What print statements did you add? Could you be more specific? It would be good to understand why you think `image` here is not modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that advanced indexing returns copies of arrays, so by doing `image[thresh==0][i][j]` all the time you modify freshly created copies which are then discarded.

Let's start with some fake data

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

original = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1024, 1024, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 100, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
copy = np.copy(original)
copy[thresh==0] = [0, 255, 0]
```

And now see what happens

```
>>> copy[thresh==0][0]
array([  0, 255,   0], dtype=uint8)
>>> copy[thresh==0][0] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> copy[thresh==0][0]
array([  0, 255,   0], dtype=uint8)
```

In order for the results to stick, you should use `numpy.where` to get the individual indices where your threshold is 0.

```
idx = np.where(thresh==0)
for row, col in zip(*idx):
    r, g, b = to_bin(copy[row,col])
    copy[row,col,0] = modified_red_pixel
    # etc
```

I would personally suggest the following so you avoid python loop and constant checks to see if you still have data to embed.

```
binary_secret_data = '01010000101010010101010001001100'
binary_secret_data = np.array(list(map(int, binary_secret_data)))
secret_len = len(binary_secret_data)

# The result is a tuple of (array of all row coords, array of all column coords)
idx = np.where(thresh==0)
# Make 3 copies of each pixel coordinate and add 0, 1, 2 repeatedly for the RGB of each pixel
idx = (np.repeat(idx[0], 3), np.repeat(idx[1], 3), np.array([0, 1, 2] * len(idx[0])))
# Only keep as many pixels as data you have to embed
idx = (idx[0][:secret_len], idx[1][:secret_len], idx[2][:secret_len])

# Boom, power of vectorisation
copy[idx] = copy[idx] & 0xfe | binary_secret_data
```

And now you can see the first 32 pixels have been successfully modified

```
>>> copy[thresh==0][:15]
array([[  0, 255,   0],
       [  1, 254,   0],
       [  0, 254,   1],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  1, 254,   0],
       [  1, 254,   1],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  1, 254,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   1],
       [  0, 254,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: It worked!! You just saved my graduation project, I might ask a question about the decoding later though. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you help me with this question? I'm struggling to get this area too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538358/looping-over-a-certain-clustered-area-in-k-means